# Combine 2D arrays to make 4D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays with shape (128,128), how would I combine them with the shape (128,128,128,128)?

Comment: You probably want some sort of outer operation, but it's unclear what you want from your question.  Please review [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Give an example of input/output for a simple case, e.g. if you had two 2x2 arrays, what should the resulting 2x2x2x2 array contain?

Comment: @TylerP The problem is that two arrays of shape `(128, 128)` only have a total of 32,768 entries while an array of size `(128, 128, 128, 128)` has ~268 million. Do you mean you want an array of shape `(2, 128, 128)`?

Comment: yes please add more info, apparently i miss understood what you were asking

Comment: if you combine two arrays of (128, 128), you get a 3D array of size (128, 128, 2), where do you get the whole other dimension and rest of the values?

Comment: If you just want to duplicate each one of your dimensions, simply use `np.broadcast_to(arr, [*arr.shape, *arr.shape])` .